# MySQL Query to group by date range?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, view

I've got a table in MySQL that shows me number of hours logged on a daily basis.  I'm trying to build a view that will allow me to quickly group my data by blocks/range of days.  The simplest case would be on a monthly basis which wouldn't be difficult.  I could just select the date as "%y-%m" and then group by that column.

Ex:

```
select time_logged, date_format(start_date, '%Y-%m') AS `month_logged`
from work_log
group by month_logged
```

That works fine if I am just grouping by month.  But my issue is that I need to group from the 13th of the month to the 12th of the following month (ex: July 13-Aug 12, Aug 13- Sept 12, etc).

Is there an easy way to do something like that in a single query/view?  I can't seem to come up with a query that works for my needs, even playing with the different date field combinations.

Comment: Do you need only the data associated with the 13th or 12th? or you just want to GROUP BY this day?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Subtract 13 days and do the grouping you are doing now:

```
select time_logged,
       date_format(start_date - interval 12 day, '%Y-%m') AS `month_logged`
from work_log
group by month_logged;
```

Comment: 12 days I think, but +1 :)

Comment: Smack.  Of course.  That would definitely be easiest.  I finally got it working with a complicated if clause, but this is so much more straightforward and obvious!  Thanks!