# MySQL group by two columns of dates as range

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database and I want to sum up the total for a given range of time. This is my table:

```
 |NO | total | start_date | completion_date |
 +---+-------+------------+-----------------+
 |1  | 12    |2017-09-11  |2017-10-11       |
 |2  | 64    |2017-12-05  |2018-02-02       |
 |3  | 22    |2017-12-12  |2018-03-01       |
 |4  | 10    |2017-12-13  |2018-07-11       |
```

Given this table I want to have the total account for each month in the given range start_date to completion_date.

For example, in line three, 22 will be the total for months December to March. The day of the week doesn't matter.

The table might be:

```
 |NO | total | date       |
 +---+-------+------------+
 |1  | 12    |2017-09     |
 |2  | 12    |2017-10     |
 |3  | 64    |2017-12     |
 |4  | 64    |2018-01     |
 |5  | 22    |2017-12     |
 |6  | 22    |2018-01     |
 |7  | 22    |2018-02     |
 |5  | 22    |2018-03     |
```

And so on...

I tried using an interval like:

```
start_date - interval 1 month
```

But I wasn't sure how to specifically do this because I have two columns, start_date and completion_date, how would it know to change this interval for each row?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Query to group by date range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194950/mysql-query-to-group-by-date-range)

Comment: I edited my question above. But I believe mine is a different because I am using two columns to find the range, and it is not a set interval? But could I use an interval in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will give you the result you're looking for:

```
(
SELECT 
  sum(total), 
  date_format(
    start_date, '%Y-%m'
  ) as dates 
FROM 
  test 
GROUP BY 
  dates
)
UNION
(
SELECT 
sum(total), 
  date_format(
    end_date, '%Y-%m'
  ) as dates 
FROM 
  test 
GROUP BY 
  dates
)
ORDER BY dates;
```

Result:

```
| sum(total) | dates   |
| ---------- | ------- |
| 12         | 2017-09 |
| 12         | 2017-10 |
| 96         | 2017-12 |
| 64         | 2018-02 |
| 22         | 2018-03 |
| 10         | 2018-07 |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d7ZzkqWLaW8twrMnCrbSnc/0)